# SpriteKit Shadow falloff does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, shadow

So I have a simple light node and an object and I get this result.[image]

and this is my code.

```
let light = SKLightNode()
light.categoryBitMask = 1
light.falloff = ... //I tried many values but nothing seems to change
addChild(light)

let block = SKSpriteNode(color: .black(), size: CGSize(90, 160))
block.zPosition = 2
block.shadowCastBitMask = 1
addChild(block)
```

I want to achieve this kind of look.

[image]

You can see the difference. Here the shadow gradually fades.

Am I doing something wrong? If not is there a 3rd party plugin that could work?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any plugins for spritekit :[